# How to create a TFS pull request from command line

Tags: tfs, pull-request

I know how to create a TFS pull request [using the web interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/pull-requests#create-a-new-pull-request). However that is very inconvenient. From the command line already I am doing this

```
git checkout -b mybranch
git add <files>
git commit -m "my changes"
git push origin mybranch
```

so I want to type another thing such as

```
create-pull-request mybranch
```

instead of going to the browser and messing around with a different user interface.  Perhaps I can do something with curl?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [VSTS CLI interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/install?view=vsts-cli-latest) that you can configure to use git aliases (see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/git?view=vsts-cli-latest)), including creating pull requests.

Comment: This is brilliant. Unfortunately my company is still using 2015.... :-(  but next year we may switch to VSTS.

Comment: Both links are dead by now.

Answer (score 2):

You could use VSTS CLI a new command line experience for managing VSTS/TFS resources.

*The Create a pull request (example) comma*nd

```
vsts pr create --title "My PR" --auto-complete
```

**Note： VSTS CLI is supported on Team Foundation Server 2017 update 2 and later.**

Before getting started with this command, learn how to [install the CLI here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/install?view=vsts-cli-latest).

More details please refer this tutorial: [**Get started with the VSTS CLI**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/get-started?view=vsts-cli-latest#create-a-pull-request)

Comment: Is git supposed to be at the start? Shouldn't it be vsts? And is there a way to populate the title and description from a commit into the PR?

Comment: @Chucky Thanks for pointing out to me. It's a wrong type. Yes it should should be VSTS at present. Have updated. No, you have manually type the title and description at present.

Comment: Both links are dead by now. Apparently, VSTS CLI doesn't exist anymore. There is now something called Azure CLI, which might, or might be not, a replacement? Even the internal links on their website are broken now.